# how to check if a datetime data is in the index of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe `df_hq` showed as follow

[image]

```
df_hq.index.values
Out[26]: 
array([('000001.SZ', Timestamp('2009-01-05 00:00:00')),
       ('000001.SZ', Timestamp('2009-01-06 00:00:00')),
       ('000001.SZ', Timestamp('2009-01-07 00:00:00')), ...,
       ('603999.SH', Timestamp('2016-03-30 00:00:00')),
       ('603999.SH', Timestamp('2016-03-31 00:00:00')),
       ('603999.SH', Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:00:00'))], dtype=object)
```

i want to know if the date in the index before i access data with the date.i try the following method。None of them worked。

```
'000001.SZ' in df_hq.index
Out[27]: True

'2009-01-05 00:00:00' in df_hq.index
Out[28]: False

pandas.Timestamp('2009-01-05 00:00:00') in df_hq.index
Out[29]: False

datetime.date(2009,1,5) in df_hq.index
Out[30]: False
```

the date 2009-01-05 actually is in the index ,however ,the answer above is false
how to check if a date in the index?

Comment: How do you create `df_hq`? Because there can be `Multiindex`, but you get index with tuples.

Comment: @jezrael  i get the `df_hq` with the code `df_hq=pandas.read_sql(r_sql,mssql_conn)`  <br/>  
then i set the index with the 

    df_hq.set_index(['secID','tradeDate'],inplace=True )

Comment: It looks like nice. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an index with tuples, you can only search easily for specific tuples.

```
('000001.SZ', Timestamp('2009-01-05 00:00:00')) in df_hq.index
```

I'd change it to a MultiIndex though for better functionality.

```
df_hq.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_hq.index.values)
```

Then you can see if `Timestamp('2009-01-05 00:00:00')` is in the index regardless of the first part of the tuple:

```
Timestamp('2009-01-05 00:00:00') in df_hq.index.levels[1]
```

Comment: @piRSquared  it works .Thanks a lot . it help a lot.